# How to extract N consecutively occurring digits from a string in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, string, substring

I have a large data set of addresses, I want to extract the pin codes wherever they are available.

An example address would be

`Star Mall, Near IBM Building, Delhi-Gurgaon Expressway, Block X, Sector 130, Block 8, Sector 130, Gurugram, Haryana 122591, India`

I need to get out 122591 from this. The location of the pin code in the address string varies.

How to go about it?

Comment: How do you distinguish the pin code from other numbers in the string? Is it by the number of digits?

Comment: Any 6 digits occurring in the address string shall be considered pin code.

Comment: Try REGEX by defining a series of 6 digits.

Comment: You can only do a WHERE using a 6 digit REGEX. You can't find and extract it in a string.